# Code that gets the difference of a Union-of- Ranges and UsedRange errors on copy-paste

Tags: excel, copy, range, vba

I have two `UDF's` that I use in general and want to create a marco with them

1. `Union of Ranges`
2. One that gets the `complement` or `difference` of a range and the used range of a sheet

I know there are other ways of doing what I am trying but want to see if I can get this method working

I get the error `That command cannot be used on multiple selections` when I try to copy the `complement` range I made

I do not see where the `multiple` selection is!

Thanks

```
Sub Test()
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range

Set r1 = Sheets("Nodes").Range("A1:D1, G1:G1, I1:K1")
Set r2 = UnionRange("Nodes", False, r1)
Set r3 = DiffRngAndUsedRange(r2, "Nodes")

'want to use like this
 DiffRngAndUsedRange(r2, "Nodes").Copy _
                                 Destination:=Sheets("X").Range("A1")

'I get the proper range if I select it with r3.Select
'I can delete the range r3 with r3.Delete
'I get error if I try to copy with r3.copy

End Sub
```

Get the Union of Ranges:
Edit, per comment updated code

```
Function UnionRange(shtName As String, useInputbox As Boolean, Optional rng As Range) As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim usedRng As Range

   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtName)

   If useInputbox = True Then
     On Error Resume Next
     Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select column(s)", Type:=8)
     On Error GoTo 0

   ElseIf useInputbox = False Then
     If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function

   End If

   With ws
      Set UnionRange = Intersect(.UsedRange, rng.EntireColumn)
   End With

End Function
```

Get the complement of Range and UsedRange:

```
Function DiffRngAndUsedRange(rngA As Range, UsedRangeShtName As String) As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngB As Range, rngC As Range, rCell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(UsedRangeShtName)
Set rngB = ws.UsedRange

For Each rCell In Union(rngA, rngB)
    If Intersect(rCell, rngA, rngB) Is Nothing Then
        If rngC Is Nothing Then
            Set rngC = rCell
        Else
            Set rngC = Union(rngC, rCell)
        End If
    End If
Next
Set DiffRngAndUsedRange = rngC

End Function
```

Comment: My guess is you are getting overlapping ranges. Try putting `debug.print r3.address` and see what you get.

Comment: Yes you are `correct` I get `$E$1:$F$51,$H$1:$H$51,$L$1:$V$51,$A$52:$V$52`.  The range is correct except the last `$A$52:$V$52` which is the `UsedRange` not sure why I am getting that

Comment: Thanks Scott this fixed it in the `UnionRange` Function I changed This `Set UnionRange = Intersect(usedRng, rng.EntireColumn)` to this `With ws
         Set UnionRange = Intersect(.UsedRange, rng.EntireColumn)
     End With`